# Sequential Criteria in Process builder

Tags: process-builder

I have a scenerio where Account.Type = 'Customer' create an opportunity record and If Account.Type ='Customer' **AND**  Account.Industry= 'Education' send out an email alert to Account owner.How to acheive this in **ONE** process builder.

[image] Instead of Stop can we have additional criteria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be the most efficient way, but try using two criteria:

Criteria 1: Account.Type = Customer *and* Account.Industry = Education. 
Action 1: Create an opportunity.
Action 2: Send an email alert to the owner.

Criteria 2: Account.Type = Customer.
Action 1: Create an opportunity.

Education customers will cause the first criteria to be TRUE and will execute the two actions.

If customer's Industry is not Education (criteria 1 is FALSE) the process will move to the second criteria, and only the action to create the opportunity will be executed.

It means you have to duplicate the Create Opportunity action, which is painful and a maintenance issue, but it should work.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the process builder action of create Record Here is descriptive link '[Learning Process Builder Auto Create a record](https://automationchampion.com/2015/02/13/getting-started-with-process-builder-part-1-auto-create-a-record/)

Comment: we can create record using process builder.Its not required to write apex trigger for it..here is the link http://blog.edlconsulting.com/cloud-computing/a-first-look-at-salesforce-com-process-builder-spring-15/